# Why is the "x" in "México" or "Texas" pronounced as the letter "j"?

Tags: ortografía, pronunciación, letras, consonantes

Even as a native speaker I don't know the reason for this: why is the "x" in *México, Texas* or *Xavier* pronounced as the letter "j"?

Comment: Don't forget about Oaxaca...

Comment: I think its because the names have a Nahuatl origin.. and the pronunciation cues are taken from there for those names.. I could be wrong :-)

Comment: @Duncan_m Yes, this is part of the answer.  Mexico was named after the Mexicas ("Me-shi-cas") Aztecs and pronounced "Meshico" at the time.  Later, it... well, [see my answer](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/245/why-mexico-and-texas-are-pronunced-as-the-letter-j/248#248).

Comment: I don't always spell "México" and "Texas", but when I do, I prefer *dos equis*.

Comment: Xavier is pronounced Shavier, not Javier.

Comment: @Serabe With names, I suspect that pronunciation and spelling vary wildly.  I know many people who spell their name one way and pronounce it another.  It is probably specific to individual preference and families.  I know this is particularly true for [American names](http://namenerds.com/uucn/advice/spelling.html)

Comment: @Richard If a person from Spain is called Xavier, chances are 99% that his name is not spanish but [catalan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_language) and therefore the correct pronunciation is indeed "SHavier".

Comment: @MackieMesser, they could also be Asturian or Galician (same pronunciation of the _X_ as in Catalan).

Comment: @MackieMesser Or from Guipuzcoa, like Xabier Arzalluz

Comment: I love this scholarly research! Thanks for taking the time, and thanks for saving your notes, and remembering them!

Comment: @flimzy Stay orthographic, my friend.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Old Spanish, words like "caja", "bajo", and "jarabe" were originally spelled with an "x", and pronounced as "sh" ([voiceless palato-alveolar sibilant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_palato-alveolar_sibilant)).

In 1815 the spellings were [officially changed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#Older_conventions) from an "x" to a "j" by the RAE, including words like "Méjico" and "Tejas".  By this time, the "j" was pronounced the same as "x" (previously it was pronounced like a French "j" ([voiced palato-alveolar sibilant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_postalveolar_fricative))).

Over time, some words (like "Méjico", "Tejas", "Oajaca", and "Javier") reverted back to the "x" spelling, but retained their "j" pronunciation.  And the letter "j" took on the "h" pronunciation that we know today.

[Here](http://www.babab.com/no05/expediente_x.htm) is an excellent article on the subject.

Comment: The archaic use of _x_ for the current sound of _j_ explains why _Don Quijote_ is spelled _Don Quixote_ in English.

Comment: Looking at Flimzy's answer, I guess this answers the historical aspect of the question without address the practical aspect.  The "foreign" words must have decided to revert back to (or keep) the "x" spelling.

Comment: But usually nobody writes Javier with X in Spanish, while the correct way to write Mexico is with X. See on DPD: http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=mexico  Usually when somebody is Xavier or Xavi, is because his name is Catalan and then read with the Catalan pronunciation for X, as Serabe said.

Comment: In Russian, today, 'x' is pronounced as in 'Tejas'. (Common origins, still in use).

Comment: @David: Or from Guipuzcoa, like Xabier Arzalluz

Comment: By all accounts I can find, `/d͡ʒ/` (English *j* sound) likely deaffricated and merged with `/ʒ/` (both spelled `⟨g⟩` before `⟨e⟩`, `⟨i⟩`; `⟨j⟩` elsewhere) before the year **1500**. In addition, `/ʒ/` had merged with `/ʃ/` (spelled `⟨x⟩`) by the 16th century. Did you mean to write *French j*? In any case, by the 17th-18th century,`/ʃ/` had already merged with `/ç/` ~ `/x/` (modern Spanish *j* sound). Also, the spelling change to *j* was made in [1815, 1832](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_orthography#Older_conventions), not the mid-to-late 1700s.

Comment: So many Spanish people pronounce "j" like the Arabic letter "خ" (like in خوخ) rather than "h". Enrique Iglesias is one example of those Spanish people.

Answer (score 10):

X pronunciation in Spanish:

> The Spanish *x* is usually pronounced as the English *ks* between vowels, or as the English *s* before consonants and at the beginning of words.  In words of foreign/indigenous origin, it is pronounced as the English *h* or *sh*.

In the two examples you provided, the origin of the words is a foreign or indigenous language:

- The name *[Texas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas)* comes from the [Caddo language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caddo_language), which was spoken by a group indigenous to the Oklahoma-Texas-Arkansas-Louisiana region.
- The name *[México](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_of_Mexico)* is Aztec in origin, so also foreign/indigenous.
- The native Spanish version of the name Xavier is *[Javier](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javier_%28nombre%29)*, and therefore pronounced with a J sound. Compare, for instance, the Wikipedia pages on [Francis Xavier in English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francis_Xavier) and [Francis Javier in Spanish](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Javier).  If the name is ever spelled as *Xavier* in Spanish, it seems it is likely to be pronounced as with an English *s* sound.
- *[Oaxaca](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oaxaca#Name)* is originally a [Nahuatl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nahuatl) word.

Comment: I read that it is pronounced "ks" before consonants (e.g. extra), in careful speech, though more often as "s".

Comment: That's a great quote... Where is it from?

Comment: @Richard: It's a paraphrase of the text used in my Spanish class here in Guadalajara. A paraphrase, because I no longer have the original text book, but I have my notes. :)

Comment: If you want to, you could link to [Letra x](http://buscon.rae.es/dpdI/SrvltGUIBusDPD?lema=x) in the Diccionario panhispánico de dudas.

Comment: "X" in place names of Native American origin can also sound like "s" as in "Xochimilco", the floating gardens in Mexico City.

Comment: @hippietrail yet in the original Nahuatl "x" is pronounced like "sh": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xochimilco

Comment: @Andy: I never remember that. I know "x" represents "sh" in Mayan languages and in fact the local pronunciation retains the "sh" sound for Mayan placenames and continues at least into Guatemala. Isla Holbox and Xela, the nickname for Quetzaltenango spring to mind.