# If certain words undergo a spelling change from "z" to "c" in order to preserve the soft sound of the "z," is there a "hard z" in Spanish?

Tags: etimología, ortografía, pronunciación

I was recently reviewing a page over at Span¡shD!ct and though I had read the following (or something similar) numerous times before, I have never stopped to really think about why the "z" must undergo the change described as follows:

> **To maintain the /k/, /g/, and /s/ sounds in the first person singular, the [c], [g], and [z] change to [qu], [gu], and [c] respectively. All other persons and all endings are regular.**
>
> --*Source: Span¡shD!ict*

For context, the page was about the preterite tense and specifically used "cruzar" as an example, explaining that the "z" in "cruzar" changes to "c" for 1st person singular -- *crucé* (not *cruzé*).

When I think of all the Spanish words I know that contain a "z," I can't think of any examples where "z" is *not* pronounced with an "s" or "soft c" sound.  Did the "z" have a hard sound at one point in time?  Or is it possible that there is another reason for this spelling change?

Thanks in advance for any insight you may have on this topic.

Comment: You're probably aware of this, but just to make sure -- when the Z appears right before certain consonants, the pronunciation changes to the type of Z we typically have in English.  Example: *juzgar*.  But note that the same thing happens to the S before those same consonants.  Example: *cisne*.

Comment: @aparente001 I actually wasn't aware of that, but I have since discovered (and have had native speakers confirm for me) that some Spanish speakers do pronounce a "z" sound, although it doesn't ever sound quite like the way it is pronounced in English.  Nevertheless, I find your comment very interesting,so thank you for adding it.  Do you know which consonants have this effect on the "z" (or "s") in the Spanish language?

Comment: *Some Spanish speakers do pronounce a "z" sound* -- would be interested to know more about this, and hear an example. // *which consonants have this effect on the "z" (or "s")?* -- the voiced consonants, e.g. N, *asno, rebuzna, juzgar*.

Comment: @aparente001 Well, for starters, I think at least some native speakers of Spanish would be surprised if you told them that the "z" sound does not exist in their language.  What I may have not made the distinction of in the past is that this applies almost exclusively to certain instances of "s" when it precedes certain consonants.

Comment: @aparente001    NTL, I do sometimes hear the "z" prounounced as a "z."  The first time I heard this was in some DELE material and the phrase was "diez de."  One of these days, I'll record it and upload it as an additional example.  In the meantime, I don't believe I've heard this in the speech of those who use [_**distinción_**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Spanish_coronal_fricatives#Distinction).  In fact, I think it may be something you're more likely to find in Mexico (if anywhere at all).  I'll give you a link to an example in my next comment.

Comment: @aparente001  Listen to [**this**](https://youtu.be/d--I30Krvqo?t=10) and then tell me what you think — doesn't the "z" in "diez" sound a lot like a "z"?  BTW, I welcome anyone to listen to this and then tell me what they think.  Even better if you know what I'm referring to and can provide some additional examples.

Comment: Some consonants are voiced and some are unvoiced.  If you sing a phrase slowly, the singing sound will be interrupted when you get to an unvoiced consonant, such as *f* or *t*.  It will not be interrupted when you get to a voiced consonant, such as *d* or hard *g*.  I'm sorry, I haven't learned the phonetic symbols.  What English speakers call the "Z" sound is a *voiced* consonant, and what we think of as the "S" or "soft C" sound is an *unvoiced* consonant.  The rule is very simple, and I have never heard an exception: a written S or Z followed by an *unvoiced* consonant...

Comment: ... will *sound* like what English speakers call the "S" sound; but if they are followed by a *voiced* consonant, they will sound like what we call the "Z" sound.  I provided examples in my previous comments. The "Un Diez de Mayo" song is another example.  In the sentence "Ya son las diez," followed by silence, the sound at the end of the word "diez" will be *unvoiced*.  In English we would call it an "S" sound.  However, in "Diez de Mayo," the sound at the end of the word "Diez" will be what English speakers would describe as a "Z" sound.  That is, it will be *voiced*.

Comment: @aparente001 is describing a phenomenon called "homorganic assimilation", which is widespread in many languages. In this, a feature of a particular phoneme changes to resemble a feature of an adjacent phoneme. In this case, the feature is voicing: the normally unvoiced Spanish /z/ assimilates the voicing of the following voiced sounds. It is not universal, and seems to occur more often in unstressed environments. The voiced /z/ which results is considered an "allophone", or a regional or contextual variant of the actual phoneme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does, in the past. It would have been pronounced as [dz] with *ç* being the unvoiced equivalent [ts]. But following phonetic changes, spelling reforms have made it such that no (native) Spanish words have an *z* followed by *e* or *i*. Those that do are generally just pronounced as if they were a *c*, but you may hear some variation as with many imported words.

Comment: Good to know, @guifa.  I truly appreciate the wealth of knowledge you bring to this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to guifa's comment, some contemporary 'native' words *do* have (RAE-accepted) spellings retaining a 'z':

- [zelote/zelota](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQelXMx), [zeugma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQwABIN), [zegrí](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQamnKY), [zendal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQmR26S), [zipizape](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRXmDGJ), [zis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRg817G), [zas](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQBzz4w), [ziranda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRZyj7V), [enzima](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Fu2c5Lc),<sup>1</sup> [zimógeno](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRKa83j), [zeda](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQR9ZTG), [zeta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQvB56G)

<sup>1. Note: not the same meaning as *encima*</sup>

While many are registered with both forms as acceptable:

| word | alternate orthography with "c" |
| --- | --- |
| [zedilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQaQFCz) | [cedilla](http://dle.rae.es/?id=863q17o) |
| [azimut](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4ejZSJ5) | [acimut](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0Tzdf1q) |
| [azimutal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0U1VOjx) | [acimutal](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0U1VOjx) |
| [eczema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EN2bZvI) | [eccema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EJE3d7t) |
| eczematoso | eccematoso |
| [ozena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RNcMUoE) | [ocena](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QrR0oxm) |
| [zebra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQP3THs) | [cebra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=859NMWz) |
| [zenit/zénit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQoIUWw) | [cenit/cénit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8DWpJ3a) |
| [zempasúchil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQiAA30) | [cempasúchil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8BqIcgM) |
| [zinzontle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRR1ChF), [zenzontle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cQuaB7v) | [cencontle](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8HDPZMp) |
| [zigoto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cR7miBO) | [cigoto](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9CTwJpN) |
| [zigofiláceo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cR17pQm) | [cigofiláceo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9CG3Qp7) |
| [zigomático](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cR18vo9) | [cigomático](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9CIlMpB) |
| [zigomorfo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cR76Qdq) | [cigomorfo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9CKh65R) |
| [zingiberáceo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRQFqUd) | [cingiberáceo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9GdbfRt) |
| [zincuate](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRO2Lnm) | [cencuate](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8CnU7Ss) |
| [zircón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRblYaz) | [circón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9JG5CVi) |
| zircona | circona |
| zirconio | circonio |
| zirconita | circonita |

And these odd doublets where there is a contemporary sound difference between the two:

| z | c |
| --- | --- |
| [despeluzar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DJeFPrR) | [despelucar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DJdazKI) |
| [dulzamara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EG6JL4v) | [dulcamara](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EFI79h3) |

In addition to the loans:

| z | c |
| --- | --- |
| [benzina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5MSZKHS) | [bencina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5LEfEYZ) |
| [zíngaro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cROvFzS) | [cíngaro](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9GdLn1P) |
| [magazín](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NsQ1KTO) | [magacín](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NsC6UpN) |

etc

And those taken from proper names:

| z | c |
| --- | --- |
| [zinc](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRNNLet) | [cinc](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Ery70I) |
| [zinnia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cRQpl8N) | [cinia](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9GjtHpy) |
| [alzhéimer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2B3Izdh) | - |

Comment: Are these words pronounced with a "z" sound similar to that found in English?  Or does it just depend on the region (or perhaps age of a person, say, someone well past his/her school days and whose knowledge about language and pronunciation rules are from days gone by)?  Also, has any decree been made by the Academy or anyone else that dictates words with "z" shall, forever more, be only pronounced with an "s" (or perhaps with the "th" sound as found in "thin")?

Comment: z and c (before i and e) always have the same sound in Spanish. Depending on your dialect, that sound can be like an 's' or like a 'th'. This is similar to 'f' and 'ph' both being spellings for the same sound in English. The English 'z' sound doesn't exist as a phoneme in Spanish, but 's' sounds *can* be pronounced like an English 'z' sound when they occur right before a consonant (e.g. *desde, rasgo, mismo, jazmín* etc), though there is a certain amount of free variation in this.

Comment: Indeed, there is a certain amount of free variation. I've even heard a "z" sound when the "z" comes at the end of a word as in "diez."  I don't really detect any such thing in the [**16 versions of it I found at Forvo**](https://forvo.com/word/diez/#es), but I swear I've heard it pronounced as such in some of my DELE prep materials. The first time I heard it, I remember thinking _What?! I thought Spanish didn't have a "z" sound._  And then, of course, I was reminded of this question I posted here and wondered if there was more of a need for this spelling change than I could fathom at the time.

Comment: In my defense I think out of that list I'd really only call zis zas and zipizapi native words :-)  Most of them are pretty obviously highly technical Latin/Greek origin or come from proper names from groups and as we see with Mexico, those are very resistant to change.  But it's a great list nonetheless to show that there are a handful of words that are simply not used with the modern ce-/ci- spelling.

Comment: With respect to the comment I made April 8, 2018 at 8:37, I think I know why I hear a "z" sound sometimes when it comes at the end of the word.  It is because, unlike  a Forvo recording, a word ending in "z" may be immediately followed by one of those consonants that tend to alter its pronunciation — the same ones that affect the "s" (b, d, voiced g, m, n, l, r or v).

Comment: If a word ending in "s" (or even sometimes "z," depending on the speaker) comes at the end of a sentence or is followed by a comma, it is likely to retain its soft "s" sound, even if the next letter is b, d, voiced g, m, n, l, r or v because there is a pause between the end of the word and the next sound uttered.