# Why do "ci/ce" and "zi/ze" both represent the /θ/ sound ? What is the historical origin of this redundancy?

Tags: etimología, historia, ortografía, lingüística, ambigüedad

I noticed that the letter "z" in Spanish is pronunced /θ/ in all circumstances, and the letter "c" is prononounced /θ/ in front of "e", "i" and /k/ in front of other vowels.

My questions are:

1. What is the origin of these two distinct spellings? Did Latin have a
   more practical reason for having two different letters that represent the same sound ?
2. Why hasn't modern Spanish reformed this redundancy, just using "z"
   everywhere ? Most other aspects of Spanish orthography seem to be completely coherent and phonetic.

A good example is the verbs ending with *-izar*, such as *tranquilizar*. In the first person preterite singular, it becomes *tranquilicé*, whereas **tranquilizé* would be pronounced the same.

Comment: This reminded me about _Los Santos Inocentes_, both the book and the movie: _la C con la A, hace KA, y la C con la I hace CI y la C con la E hace CE y la C con la O hace KO, y los porqueros y los pastores, y los muleros, y los gañanes y los guardas se decían entre sí desconcertados, también te tienen unas cosas, parece como que a los señoritos les gustase embromamos, pero no osaban levantar la voz, hasta que una noche, Paco (...) se encaró con el señorito alto (...) preguntó, señorito Lucas, y ¿a cuento de qué esos caprichos? (...) es la gramática, oye, el porqué pregúntaselo a los académicos_

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya I think you're mistaking /θ/ for something else. English /θ/ is never represented by anything other than *th*.

Comment: Only few local areas in Spain pronounce these like /θ/." Most dialects pronounce these like /s/. In English also,  "c" is pronounced /s/ in front of "e", "i" and /k/ in front of other vowels. In English also, there are words like "quartz" and "influenza", which pronounce the "z" like /s/."

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Historically](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26692/18348) they did represent different sounds, but have since merged in Spanish:

[image]

The usual orthography in modern Spanish for /θ/ is "c" before "e, i" and "z" elsewhere.

However, [some words](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25713/18348) (mostly loans) contradict this for [etymological](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/10328/revisions-of-spanish-orthography-qu%c3%a9-revisiones-ha-tenido-la-ortograf%c3%ada-espa%c3%b1) reasons, having "ze, zi" sequences. Note that many of these have 'hispanicised' variants, e.g. *zinc, cinc; zebra, cebra*.

Comment: Does it mean that tranquilicé was read "tranquilitsé" in 13-15 th century ?

Comment: @Mintou you picked an unfortunate example, since "tranquilizar" is a relatively new word, coined in the 18th century, but yes, that would be the then spelling to represent that pronunciation (early in that period, and similar to "tranquilisé" by the end of it). See here for more info: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Spanish_coronal_fricatives#Historical_evolution

Comment: sorry for being insistent, but why would a new 18th century word not use the form "tranquilizé", what was the logic behind it ?

Comment: I mean, since in the 18th century there was not such distinction anymore, is it completely arbitrary that they kept this rule in from front of e and i ?