# ¿Por qué la equis se pronuncia /ks/ en algunos topónimos mexicanos?

Tags: pronunciación, méxico, letras, topónimos

La letra X representaba históricamente la fricativa palatal sorda [ʃ], consonante normal en el español del s. XVI que luego sufrió cambios hasta llegar a pronunciarse [x], o sea como fricativa velar sorda. Este cambio se nota en algunos topónimos tales como *México* y *Xalapa*. Ahora, también mantiene la pronunciación grecorromana /ks/, pero ésta se encuentra mayoritariamente en palabras de origen griego (*asfixia*) y palabras que contienen el prefijo *ex*- (*exhibir, exigir,* etc.)

Mi pregunta es: en los topónimos mexicanos que contienen una equis que se pronuncia /ks/, ¿ésta representa la consonante (o secuencia de consonantes) correcta a partir de la lengua originaria? (No descarto la posibilidad de que esta letra haya representado la secuencia de consonantes /ks/ ab inicio, pero me parece dudoso).

Teniendo en cuenta el inventario consonántico de las lenguas que brindaron la toponimia mexicana, ¿cómo se habría pronunciado originalmente...

¿*Tlaxcala* (/Tlakskala/ o /Tlaʃkala/)?

¿*Tuxtla* (/Tukstla/ o /Tuʃtla/)?

Habrá más ejemplos, pero estos se me han destacado desde siempre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Tlaxcallān > Tlaxcala

La pronunciación Nahuatl de las *x* es siempre /ʃ/,<sup>1</sup> y de *Tlaxcallān* era /t͡ɬaʃˈkal.laːn/.

### Tuchtlán > Tuxtla

Pero *Tuxtla* viene de *Tochtlán* <sub>(nahuatl)</sub> via *Tuchtlán* <sub>(zoque)</sub>, así que se solía pronunciar [tuːtʃtɬ͡a]:

> Por su parte, los zoques apropiaron el nombre de Tochtla a su lengua y la llamaron Tuchtlán, lo mismo hicieron los españoles que la denominaron, en diversas épocas, Tusta, Tucstla y, finalmente, Tuxtla. El nombre del municipio en náhuatl (Tuchtlán) rescata el nombre primitivo del valle de Tuxtla, lugar donde los zoques fundaron la actual ciudad de
>   Tuxtla Gutiérrez, Chiapas.

- [*Bosquejos históricos de Tuxtla Gutiérrez*](http://www.conecultachiapas.gob.mx/publications/download/20151013bosquejos-historicos.pdf) (p.135) (conecultachiapas.gob.mx)

Nótese que en general en castellano la *x* se pronuncia /ks/ antes de un consonante, y de ahí la motivación de esta ortografía:

> En posición final de sílaba seguida de consonante, se pronuncia como /ks/ o /gs/ en el español de América

- https://www.rae.es/dpd/x

---

<sup>1. [An Introduction to Classical Nahuatl](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=NvThNb2wmUcC&q=table%201.2) (pp.4-5)</sup>
<sup>2. [Lingüística Misionera II](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GU5tfb3kMaEC&pg=PA63&lpg=PA63&dq="<x>")</sup>
<sup>3. [*Las Lenguas del Chiapas colonial: Lengua zoque*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?redir_esc=y&id=w75lmgEACAAJ), Appendix: La ortografía colonial y la fonología de la lengua zoque</sup>
<sup>3. [Do Mexicans still pronounce the "x" in any Nahuatl place names the Nahuatl way?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/23602/do-mexicans-still-pronounce-the-x-in-any-nahuatl-place-names-the-nahuatl-way)</sup>